# quasi convexity of a function and maximum value of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\tau$ and $\beta$ be positive numbers such that $\beta > \frac{1}{\log(1+\tau)}$ and:
\begin{equation}
\label{EQ:fx}
f(x) = x \log \left( 1 + \frac{\tau}{(x-1) \beta \tau + 1} \right). 
\end{equation}
Then $f(x) \leq f(1)$ for all real numbers $x \geq 1$.

Sloution:
\begin{equation}
\label{EQ:y:x}
y = (x - 1) \beta + \frac{1}{\tau}.
\end{equation}
Then 
\begin{equation}
\label{EQ:fx:gy}
f(x) = g(y), 
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
\label{EQ:gy}
g(y) = \left( \frac{y}{\beta} + 1 - \frac{1}{\tau \beta} \right) \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{y} \right). 
\end{equation}
Now, a sufficient condition for a function $h(\cdot)$ to be quasi-convex is provided by the following property

If $h^{\prime \prime}(y) > 0$ whenever $h^{\prime}(y) = 0$, then $h(\cdot)$ is quasi-convex.

We will now show using above property that $g(\cdot)$ is quasi-convex, and deduce quasi-convexity of $f(\cdot)$ from it.
Next, it is easy to show using L'H\^{o}pital's rule that: 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)  =  \frac{1}{\beta} <  \log \left(1 + \tau \right) = f(1).(Given Condition)  
\label{EQ:lim:fx}
\end{equation}
Now, consider the sublevel set:
[
S = {x $\geq$ 1 | $f(x) \leq f(1)$ }. 
]
By above eq., there exists $x^{\prime} > 1$ such that $x \in S$ for all $x \geq x^{\prime}$. Also, clearly $1 \in S$. Since $f(\cdot)$ is quasi-convex, the set $S$ is convex; so $x \in S$ for all $x \geq 1$. That is, $f(x) \leq f(1)$ for all $x \geq 1$ and the result follows.

Can we do the same thing by using some properties of quasi convex function, if function changes to 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = x (1-\alpha)\left(\log \left( 1 + \frac{\tau}{(x-1) \beta \tau + 1} \right)\right)^{(1-\alpha)}, \forall x\geq1, \forall \alpha<1. 
\end{equation}

Comment: Similarly, can we prove same property using the same lines of concept with some properties for the function                                                                     \begin{equation}
f(x) = x \log \log\left( 1 + \frac{\tau}{(x-1) \beta \tau + 1} \right). \forall x\geq1
\end{equation}